# legend size in Highcharts under ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, highcharts, size

everything is in the title, I really don't know how I can change the legend's size of my pie.

The code to render it is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    var chart;

        chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
            chart: {
                renderTo: 'pie',
                plotBackgroundColor: null,
                plotBorderWidth: null,
                plotShadow: false
            },
            title: {
             text: 'Title aligned left',
        },
            tooltip: {
                formatter: function() {
                    return '<b>'+ this.point.name +'</b>: '+ this.percentage.toFixed(2) +' %';
                }
            },
            plotOptions: {
                pie: {
             enableMouseTracking: false,
                    shadow: false,
                    animation: false,
                    allowPointSelect: true,
                    cursor: 'pointer',
                    verticalAlign: String,
                    dataLabels: {
                        enabled: true,
                        color: "#2B0057",
                        connectorColor: '#2B0057',
                    }
                }
            },
});
```

Does anyone know Highcharts and have a solution ? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The overall "size" of the legend is a combination of many factors ([itemDistance](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#legend.itemDistance), [margins](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#legend.margin), [itemMargins](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#legend.itemMarginBottom), [explicit width](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#legend.width) etc..).

I'm guessing what you really care about though is the text size.  Use [legend.itemStyle](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#legend.itemStyle) for that:

```
legend: {
    itemStyle: {
        fontSize: '20pt'
    }
},
```

Comment: doesn't seem to work, the size doesn't change whether I put '1pt' or '100pt' :/

Comment: ok, i guess my problem must be coming from somewhere else :/. thanks anyway!